# Why does setting the allowfullscreen attribute of an iframe doesn't seem to keep the attribute

Tags: javascript, iframe, reactjs

In my code I am setting the allowfullscreen attribute of my iframe which is surrounded by SkyLight which is an npm module for modal views in react.js

```
            <SkyLight dialogStyles={myBigGreenDialog} hideOnOverlayClicked ref="simpleDialog">
              <iframe src=url frameborder="0" width="960" height="569" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>;
            </SkyLight>
```

However when I check the page my iframe does not have the property allowfullscreen:
[image: pre editing]

When I manually add the attribute `allowfullscreen="true"` in the console, however, the iframe can go full screen.

Does anyone know how to make sure the allowfullscreen attribute exists without manually adding it through the console?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://react.dev/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx#3-camelcase-salls-most-of-the-things).

JSX, which React uses for generating DOM, is **case sensitive**. It's attributes are named after DOM properties, not HTML attributes (although many DOM properties are named after HTML attributes).

The attribute is called `allowFullScreen`, not `allowfullscreen`. It is also a boolean attribute so `”true”` is not a valid value for it (the string will be cast to the boolean `true`, but so would the string `"false"`).

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

[see a live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/52404/)

Comment: Buit it says lowercase here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#allowfullscreen

Comment: @Toniq — That's documenting HTML. This question is about JSX.

Answer (score -3):

Yeah, when I am manually adding `allowfullscreen="true"` then it's working fine. Below is the example of my code -

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="example-embed-code" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: I voted down because this is not an answer.

Comment: Sorry @Take-Some-Bytes, now I have written a more clear answer. Thank you.